# Blackberry Simulator Installation and Java Virtual Machine Load Failed

Tags: blackberry, jvm

Blackberry Simulator can't be loaded due to incompatible Java Virtual Machine. How to know which JVM is perfect for Blackberry QNX Momentics Native SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the Simulator used for BB10 Native Development (using C/C++ Cascades)?  Presuming you do, this simulator is run as a Virtual Machine using VMware, not as a Java VM.  You will find more of the requirements and installation details using this page:
[BB10 Simulator Requirements](http://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/simulator_systemrequirements.html)